# Picking random number between two points in C

Tags: c, random

I was wondering, is it possible to generate a random number between two limits in c. I.e. my program is set like this:

```
function x
{
    generate random number;
}

while(1)
{
    function x;
    delay
}
```

so bascially I want a random number to be generated everytime the function is called , but the number has to be between, for example, 100 and 800

I know there is a already made function called random and randmize in `stdlib.h`
I just dont know how to create the upper and lower limits

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, don't forget to seed your PRNG **once and only once**:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Then, this function *should* do what you want.
*(lightly tested, seems to work)*

```
int RandRange(int Min, int Max)
{
    int diff = Max-Min;
    return (int) (((double)(diff+1)/RAND_MAX) * rand() + Min);
}
```

In your case, you'll want to:

```
x = RandRange(100, 800);  /* x will be between 100 and 800, inclusive */
```

This uses floating-point math, which may be slower than modulo (%) arithmetic, but will have less bias.

Comment: Is there a way to generate a number number between two limits without usinf the sran and rand function

Comment: What it is that i have a while (1) (super loop) which calls a function every 10 ms seconds.

Comment: If you want a random number, you have to use rand(), or write your own PRNG.

Answer (score 3):

First get a random number between 0 and 1 (`R`). Then scale this to the desired range (`R* (right limit - left limit)`). Then add the min desired value.

```
int rand_between(int l, int r) {
  return (int)( (rand() / (RAND_MAX * 1.0f)) * (r - l) + l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the modulus operator.

```
int r = rand();
r = (r % 700) + 100;
```

700 is the difference of the range.

Comment: modulus might generate biased random numbers because a range might contain non-uniform modulus mappings.

Comment: If so I believe the generator would already have been biased and bad.  Whether making that situation worse is good or bad is debatable since making it worse increases the likeliness of discovery and improvement.

Comment: @perreal has a better answer.  I posted this one for clarity.  I don't know how the poster intends to use the answer.  Good enough might be good enough.

Comment: @Joe:  The generator can be PERFECT, and modulo still creates a bias.  Consider the very simple case, where RAND_MAX = 10, and you do a modulo 3.  With perfect distribution, you'll get 40% Zeros, 40% Ones, and only 30% Twos, ergo: Bias against Two(2) in this simple case.  The bias is harder to see with Large numbers, but it is still there.

Comment: @abelenky Yes, my error. I admit I worry about the algorithm more myself. If I had the ability to set the rand_max, I wouldn't be using mod; and the normal RAND_MAX is spec'd for: 'This value is library dependent, but is granted to be at least 32767.'

Comment: It's not always true, for example if
int r = 9 and range is (2,10) r = (9%10)+2 = 11 that is out of range