# generate random a number number between two limits

Tags: c

Is there a way to generate a number number between two limits without using the sran and rand function
 What it is that i have a while (1) (super loop) which calls a function every 10 ms seconds. in the function a for loop is used to create a delay, but, everytime the function is access the delay should be different but between two limts, 8 and 2 ms, `for(x=0;x<random_number;x++)`

Comment: Why not use `rand()` and scale appropriately?

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to use rand?

Comment: What are "ms seconds"? "Monstrously slow seconds"?

Comment: @KerrekSB - One ms second is the minimum amount of time that it takes to get cash from an ATM machine.

Comment: And [you already asked this question...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571738/picking-random-number-between-two-points-in-c)

Comment: firstly its is not homework,its a project im doing myself, basically with rand() i'm getting almost the same delay duration,i just need to create a random delay every the function is access, like i have work it out , to create an 8ms delay i use `for(x=0;x<1580;x++)` and for a 2ms delay , i use `for(x=0;x<358;x++)`, so i want a random number to generate between 358 and 1580.

Comment: Use `rand()`, scale appropriately, and cast to an `int`.

Comment: @user1175889: If you are always getting the same result, then you are doing something wrong.  Post some code.

Comment: ` unsigned int  x,y;
 
 y=rand()%1223 + 358;
 for (x=0;x<y;x++);` this is the code im using so far, i did as jack maney said, thanks by the way jack, i think i got the scaling wrong, as i do get random delays but some like at 10 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow hope this will answer your question.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int iMaxRand =100,ii=0 ;
    while( ii < 100)
    {
         printf("Random Number is:%d\n", rand() % iMaxRand);
         ii++;
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: you need to use srand so it will be trully (pseudo) random I think.

Comment: If we do not specify it will 1 as default value but good to use srand based on our requirement